# Running Composite Tests with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, headless

I want to automate some technical tests on an entire domain. These test can be loadspeed, Yslow Grade, Js errors, Response Status Code Check... I successful created a spider script that grabs all urls for a given domain, but today I have some problems when implementing these tests.

Basically, imagine you want to grab a known list of metrics from an unknow list of urls. How will you achieve this ?

I have two options from my point of view :

- Create a module for each test and invoke them for each url in a parent script

  This can be correct, but some scripts are open source like yslow.js : no sure I will be able to convert them and they won't be runnable any more (because of the module)
- ReInvoke phantomjs with the new child-process-module (execFile or spawn)

  I will loose control on the execution, and would certainly have performance problems.

Maybe my understanding is not correct. Are scripts limited to a single action on an unique url ? Every example that I can see on the web is always for one (or a static list) of urls.

I am aware that PhantomJS is not a test framework, it is only used to launch the tests via a suitable test runner. Maybe I am trying to do to many things with Phantom and I should try to keep scripts as simple as possible.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First - You may want to look into CasperJS.  It runs on top of Phantom and makes it lightyears easier to chain events together.

Second - It seems like you could just setup all of your metric scripts to run sequentially, then wrap that in a for loop, and pass in a list of URLs into that loop.

```
urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.bing.com'];

for each(url in urls) {
    phantom.load(url, function(page) {
        runMetrics(page);
    }
}
```

That's a bit pseudocode-y, but would something like that work?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but this do not help me so much. CasperJS is  a navigation scripting lib with  some unit testing feature. Your pseudo code is correct and I have already the same in my crawler.

Comment: @Cybermaxs Does your comment mean you've solved your problem? Or is your question still unanswered? (I was going to suggest the same as Ryan).